# ignore null object in array when parse with Codable swift

Tags: json, swift, parsing, codable, swift4.2

i'm parsing this API with swift Codable

```
"total": 7,
"searchResult": [
    null,
    {
        "name": "joe"
        "family": "adam"
    },
    null,
    {
        "name": "martin"
        "family": "lavrix"
    },
    {
        "name": "sarah"
        "family": "mia"
    },
    null,
    {
        "name": "ali"
        "family": "abraham"
    }
]
```

with this `PaginationModel`:

```
class PaginationModel<T: Codable>: Codable {
    var total: Int?
    var data: T?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case total
        case data = "searchResult"
    }

    required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        self.total = try container.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey: .total)
        self.data = try container.decodeIfPresent(T.self, forKey: .data)
    }
}
```

and `User` Model:

```
struct User: Codable {
    var name: String?
    var family: String?
}
```

i call `jsonDecoder` like this to parse API json:

```
let responseObject = try JSONDecoder().decode(PaginationModel<[User?]>.self, from: json)
```

now my problem is `null` in `searchResult` Array. it parsed correctly and when i access to `data` in `paginationModel` i found `null` in array.

how can i ignore all `null` when parsing API, and result will be an array without any `null`

Comment: @user28434 i updated my question

Comment: yes with this ?, it normally parsed to null. i want an array without null object

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the first place, I would advise to always consider `PaginationModel` to be composed from arrays. You don't have to pass `[User]` as the generic type, you can just pass `User`. Then the parser can use the knowledge that it parses arrays and handle `null` automatically:

```
class PaginationModel<T: Codable>: Codable {
    var total: Int?
    var data: [T]?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case total
        case data = "searchResult"
    }

    required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        self.total = try container.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey: .total)

        self.data = (try container.decodeIfPresent([T?].self, forKey: .data))?.compactMap { $0 }
    }
}
```

You might want to remove optionals here and use some default values instead:

```
class PaginationModel<T: Codable>: Codable {
    var total: Int = 0
    var data: [T] = []

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case total
        case data = "searchResult"
    }

    required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        self.total = (try container.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey: .total)) ?? 0

        self.data = ((try container.decodeIfPresent([T?].self, forKey: .data)) ?? []).compactMap { $0 }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd also recommend making total (likely) and data (definitely) required rather than Optional. That will simplify this a lot by getting rid of the decodeIfPresent. (Similarly, are name and family really Optional? Is there a difference between "missing" and empty string?)

Comment: @RobNapier Very true.

Comment: this is exactly what i want. tnx @Sulthan

Comment: @RobNapier i agree with you. but our server side developer said that if suddenly they came with null value ( because of bugs from server or ... ) you must handle it

Comment: Even so, you're better off making them mandatory, and defaulting them to empty strings in the decoder so you don't have to treat them as optional everywhere in the program.

Comment: what is best practice for this? can you write some code? please

Comment: @Sajjad Updated.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution, filter `data` after decoding

```
let responseObject = try JSONDecoder().decode(PaginationModel<[User?]>.self, from: data)
responseObject.data = responseObject.data?.filter{$0 != nil}
```

Comment: this can be a solution, but i'm looking for a better solution. especially all thing to be done in PaginationModel

Comment: The problem is that generic `T` can be a single object as well as an array. The **best** solution is to filter the `null` values already on the server.

Comment: @Sajjad, `PaginationModel` currently doesn't have enough information about actual type used in generic, you would have to pass info that you're actually looking for `Array` and then in `init(from decoder: Decoder)` decode it as `[T?]` first and then `compactMap` it to `[T]` and save into property.

Comment: ok. if i change `data : T?` to `data: [T?]`, then can i handle it?

Answer (score 0):

You may add an array type check within decode :

```
  required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    self.total = try container.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey: .total)
    self.data = try container.decodeIfPresent(T.self, forKey: .data)

    //add the following:
    if let array =  self.data as? Array<Any?> {
        self.data = ( array.compactMap{$0} as? T)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Note, you can just define the decodable variable that may be null/nil as [Float?] (or whatever type), with the optional '?' inside the array brackets.